# PHP contact form issue (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: javascript, php, html, email, contacts

**PHP CODE**

```
$name_error = $email_error =  "";
$name = $email = $message = $success = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $name_error = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
      $name_error = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $email_error = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $email_error = "Invalid email format"; 
    }
  }

    if (empty($_POST["subject"])) {
    $subject_error = "Subject is required";
  } else {
    $subject = test_input($_POST["subject"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $message = "";
  } else {
    $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
  }

  $to = "ayoub.kermout@gmail.com"
  $about = "GA:TC CONTACT RECIVED!!"
  $body = "Name: $name\nEmail: $email\nSubject: $subject\nMessage: $message"

  mail($to, $about, body, "From: $name <$email>")
  $success = "Message sent, thank you for contacting us!";
  $name = $email = $message = '';

}
}
?>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
(function($) {
  "use strict"; // Start of use strict

  // Smooth scrolling using jQuery easing
  $('a.js-scroll-trigger[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: (target.offset().top - 48)
        }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo");
        return false;
      }
    }
  });

  // Closes responsive menu when a scroll trigger link is clicked
  $('.js-scroll-trigger').click(function() {
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
  });

  // Activate scrollspy to add active class to navbar items on scroll
  $('body').scrollspy({
    target: '#mainNav',
    offset: 48
  });

  // Collapse the navbar when page is scrolled
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($("#mainNav").offset().top > 100) {
      $("#mainNav").addClass("navbar-shrink");
    } else {
      $("#mainNav").removeClass("navbar-shrink");
    }
  });

  // Scroll reveal calls
  window.sr = ScrollReveal();
  sr.reveal('.sr-icons', {
    duration: 600,
    scale: 0.3,
    distance: '0px'
  }, 200);
  sr.reveal('.sr-button', {
    duration: 1000,
    delay: 200
  });
  sr.reveal('.sr-contact', {
    duration: 600,
    scale: 0.3,
    distance: '0px'
  }, 300);

  // Magnific popup calls
  $('.popup-gallery').magnificPopup({
    delegate: 'a',
    type: 'image',
    tLoading: 'Loading image #%curr%...',
    mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
    gallery: {
      enabled: true,
      navigateByImgClick: true,
      preload: [0, 1]
    },
    image: {
      tError: '<a href="%url%">The image #%curr%</a> could not be loaded.'
    }
  });

})(jQuery);
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto text-center">
              <h2 class="section-heading text-white">CONTACT FORM</h2>
              <hr class="light">
              <p class="text-faded">Fill the form table down below to contact us.</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-center">                        
        <h2>Contact</h2>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
          <form id="contact-form" class="form" action="mail/contact.php" method="post" role="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="form-label" for="name">Your Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your name" tabindex="1" required>
              </div>                            
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="form-label" for="email">Your Email</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" tabindex="2" required>
              </div>                            
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="form-label" for="subject">Subject</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" tabindex="3">
              </div>                            
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="form-label" for="message">Message</label>
                  <textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="message" class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Message..." tabindex="4" required></textarea>                                 
              </div>
              <div class="text-center">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-start-order">Send Message</button>
              </div>
          </form>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**PROBLEM:**
As you can see that my PHP, JS, HTML code for the contact form, But for some reason it doesn't work!!??
Every time I try to use it I keep getting (method not allowed)!!!??
I most tried everything (new PHP code different html code)
and note (I'm using it on a site hosted on glitch) it doesn't officially support PHP but it does.

Comment: This is not the minimum code needed to reproduce the problem. Please try re-asking your question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried you code. It should work except it should be `$body` instead of `body` in `mail($to, $about, body, "From: $name <$email>");`.

So the problem should be from the host provider.

BTW: Gmail seems having more strict security policy. I failed on Gmail and tried another mail service and succeed to receive the email.

Comment: ok i will try using a hotmail or yahoo if it didn't work i will use a different host. (Thnaks for the fast respond)